# Castle Windsor - Registering Generic and Non-Generic types from the same service

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I Have the following Structure

```
public SomeMessage : IServiceMessage
{
}

public MultipleMessage<T> : IServiceMessage
    where T : IServiceMessage
{
}
```

Currently I am registering all the non-generic message types (like the example I gave first) with the following registration:

```
container.Register(
    Types.FromAssemblyContaining<IServiceMessage>()
            .BasedOn<IServiceMessage>()
            .WithService.FromInterface()
            .LifestyleTransient());
```

This, however, will not register the generic MultipleMessage, so to do that I am registering all possible ones like this:

```
container.Register(
    Component.For<IServiceMessage>()
                .ImplementedBy<MultipleMessage<SomeMessage>>()
                .LifeStyle.Transient);
```

But this seems wrong, because I'm using convention for the non-generic types and going with configuration for the generic types. Is there a way to register MultipleMessage<> for all the possible generic types?

Comment: If you were to ask Windsor for all `IServiceMessage` implementations, what would you expect it to give you? How would it know what type parameter to apply to `MultipleMessage<T>`?

Comment: I have a TypedFactoryFacility going through a selector. All that is working if I register all types specifically for MultipleMessage<T>. But this breaks my configuration by convention and forces people keeping this code to change the service installer when new message types are implemented.